# iphone 5, ios 9.0.2 stuck on lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios

Anyone have solution for my issue? My iphone 5, ios 9.0.2 stuck on lock screen.

Sleep / wake button is not working for years (https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-sleepwakebutton/). I live in Indonesia, bought that iphone in Singapore. All I can say is, I can't ask for replacement

What works for me:

- assisitive touch
- home button
- mute / unmute switch
- volume up / down while accessing "Voice Control"

Other than that nothing's working

**Touch screen on OTHER than assisitive touch is not working.** So I can't do any slide, etc.

I tried to use assisitive touch to turn off my iphone but I can't swipe the "slide to power off". I can show control center via assisitive touch but I can't touch anything. **Hard reset (holding sleep/wake + home button) is not working because my sleep/wake button is not working.**

I think it might be related with "notification center" because I can't open notification center via assisitive touch.

All I can do right now is waiting till my battery runs out (hope this issue will be gone after it restarts)

**In web programming terms, it seems that there are some kind of z-index difference blocking the layer other than "Assisitive Touch layer"**

What was happening (in case any of you can replicate it):

- my wife was borrowing my iphone (LCD still off)
- WhatsApp chat notification came
- she clicked home button (while the LCD still glowing)
- boom! that's all

PS:
I don't want to wipe my iphone, I have a lot of important data in my iphone

Comment: Can you connect it to a computer with itunes?  Simply making a backup sometimes works some magic.  Of course you could afterwards completely restore it from backup if nothing helps. (Note - use the password encryption, passwords are not backed up otherwise)

Comment: I didn't want to connect it to computer because it will charge the battery hence it took longer time to wait until the battery exhausted. But I'm a bit desperate so I'll give it a shot, preparing for the worst case.

Comment: I can't do "restore backup" because I need to turn on "find my iphone" first. maann now my battery is at 90%

Comment: Thats annoying. Just brainstorming for last ideas... Is there a way on icloud.com you turn it on from your computer?  Or could you give yourself a call - maybe this will cause something useful.

Comment: I did give a call and I can't answer it because I can't do swipe to answer it. I also tried to use icloud.com, sometimes it did detect (weird, isn't that mean my "find my iphone" is on) my iphone (sometimes not) but I still can't restore backup via itunes because of that previous message. I appreciate your ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution should be to wait until the battery is drain out and the plug it to the power source to turn it on. Everything should be back to normal.**

BUT in my case, I can't wait until the battery is drain out so I open the iphone by myself then unplug the battery (~4 hours ago). Everything should be back to normal BUT in my case, it made my iphone "broken". I did a mistake (I was separating the display from the front panel!!) when I tried to "[suck](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+5+Power+Button+Replacement/10703#s38492)" the front panel. Sometimes there are some weird mark on the top of my display and touch on that area is not working :(

Though I'm not sure, is that happened because of my mistake during opening the front panel OR because I forcibly unplug the battery when the iphone is still ON.

**So, it is not advisable to open the iphone by yourself.** I did that because I really need it at that moment and I can't wait until the battery is drain out (even until now it still 64%).

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue. Waiting for battery to drain out. Taking forever.

Notification centre is open and stuck there.Touch works only on the centre, rest half of the screen is non responsive. All i can do is go through my notifications and probably call someone who's call I've missed. I can't even end the call.

Comment: after battery drain out, it works good! pheeeww

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Siri (if enabled). Instead of asking unlock my iPhone, ask for opening any app:

> "Open the Settings App"

for example. You could then go to your homescreen after entering the code (no swiping here).

Because the phone is still working, you should make a backup of the important information.

Comment: touching is not working either, I wish Siri can turn of my phone (though in my case, Siri was off)

Comment: What kind of information do you have? Sometimes backing up and starting from zero works.

Comment: restore via itunes was not working because itunes said that "find my phone" was turned off. I did discuss that on the comments above, I'll update it to the main description

Answer (score 0):

Touch home button and sleep/wake button together, and hold. After few second your phone will restart.
Hope this resolve.

Comment: I wish my sleep/wake button was working

Answer (score 0):

hold home and power button pressed for a while and it will shut down.

Comment: that would be my first thing to do if my sleep/wake button is working

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but may still help others:

Getting a **new notification** seemed to make it work again.

So either get someone to text you, setup a new calendar event on your computer or send an email. Anything that gives a notification. Then it should recognise user input again.

Tried this on my phone 3/4 times, and a friend's phone, worked on both.

Answer (score -3):

This will help!

Spread the word!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S04lPPdPsfw

Comment: unfortunately my sleep/wake button was not working so I can't do that :(